# Need help editing some text in AngularJS - simple nest of paragraphs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and I am editing an already existing website.

Let's say I have a list as described below

```
Activities
 . Dancing
 . Singing
 . Sports
 . Volleyball
 . Tennis
```

I can show this just fine on the website.
However, I want "Volleyball" and "Tennis" to be nested below "Sports" and indented like below:

```
Activities
. Dancing
. Singing
. Sports
    . Volleyball
    . Tennis
```

Here is my code.

In the .html I have

```
<div class="basic-page__section-header" ng-if="section.sectionHeader">{{section.sectionHeader }}</div>
     <pre>
        <div class="basic-page__section-list--undecorated" ng-if="section.sectionUndecoratedList">
            <ul class="section-list section-list--undecorated">
                <li ng-repeat="listItem in section.sectionUndecoratedList">{{ listItem }}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </pre>
</div>
```

Now in the .js file I use the sectionUndecoratedList in the following way:

```
sectionHeader: "Activities:",
sectionUndecoratedList: [
"Dancing",
"Singing",
"Sports",
"Volleyball",
"Tennis",
```

This is where I have the problem. I have tried a bunch of things, but I cannot nest the sports under the Sports field like this:

Sports

```
. Volleyball

. Tennis
```

It might seem easy for some, but I've been struggling with this, so help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please use [angular recursive templates](http://benfoster.io/blog/angularjs-recursive-templates) to build this, the simple array shown in the question cannot do this.

Answer (score 2):

Change your object structure like this.

```
$scope.sectionUndecoratedList = [
{"activity":"Dancing"},
{"activity":"Singing"},
{"activity":"Sports", "subactivity":["vollyBall", 
"Tennis"]}]
```

And access it from html as following way

```
`<ul>
<li ng-repeat="listItem in sectionUndecoratedList">
<div>{{ listItem.activity }}</div>
<ul ng-if="listItem.hasOwnProperty('subactivity')"
ng-repeat="l in listItem.subactivity"><li>{{ l }}</li></ul>
</li>
</ul>`
```

Sharing JsFiddle link for your referance 
https://jsfiddle.net/Prasanna15/8n5dwpab/

Answer (score 1):

You just have to change the structure of the data you store in the controller. You have to make an array of an object as shown below.

```
    $scope.sectionHeader = 'Activities';
    $scope.sectionUndecoratedList = [
      {'activites':'Dancing'},
      {'activites':'Singing'},
      {'activites':'Sports', children:['Volleyball','Tennis']}
    ]
```

Now just write ng-repeat like

```
<div>{{sectionHeader}}</div>
  <ul>
    <li 
        ng-repeat="(key,header) in sectionUndecoratedList">
      <div>
        {{header.activites}}
      </div>
      <ul ng-if="header.children">
        <li ng-repeat="h in header.children">{{h}}</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Sharing the working demo for your reference http://jsbin.com/qozaduruti/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use object js structure

plus a nested ng-repeat i will write a plunker soon

Comment: Thank you guys. Makes sense. A plunker would be helpful!